# Bash check if path contains two folders

Tags: bash, search, path, directory

How can I search an arbitrary path and determine if it has two folder names? The folder names can appear in any position in either order. Not a shell expert so seeking help here.

```
if [ -p "$PATH" ]; then
  echo "path is set"
else
  echo "path is not set"
fi
```

I found this segment but I'm not sure it's useful. $PATH is a special variable correct?

Comment: do you mean that the folder has to contain exactly 2 subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me make sure I understand the question right. You have some path (like "/home/sam/foo/bar/baz") and you want to test whether it contains two specific directory names (e.g. "foo" and "bar") in either order, right? So, looking for "foo" and "bar":

- `/home/sam/foo/bar/baz` would match
- `/mnt/bar/subdir/foo` would also match
- `/mnt/bar/foo2` would *not* match, because "foo2" is not "foo"

If that's correct, you can do this in bash as two tests:

```
dir1="foo"
dir2="bar"
if [[ "/$path/" = *"/$dir1/"* && "/$path/" = *"/$dir2/"* ]]; then
    echo "$path" contains both $dir1 and $dir2"
else
    echo "$path" does not contain both $dir1 and $dir2"
fi
```

Notes:

- This is using the `[[ ]]` conditional expression, which is different from `[ ]` and not available in basic shells. If you use this type of expression, you need to start the shell script with a shebang that tells the OS to run it with bash, not a generic shell (i.e. the first line should be either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and do not run it with the `sh` command (that will override the shebang).
- The way the comparison works is that it sees whether the path matches both the patterns `*"/$dir1/"*` and `*"/$dir2/"*` -- that is, it matches those names, with a slash at each end, maybe with something else (`*`) before and after. But since the path might not start and/or end with a slash, we add them (`"/$path/"`) to make sure they're there.
- Do *not* use `PATH` as a variable in your script -- it's a very special variable that tells the shell where to find executable commands. If you ever use it for anything else, your script will suddenly start getting "command not found" errors. Actually, there are a bunch of all-caps special-meaning variables; to avoid conflicts with them, use lowercase or mixed-case variables for your things.